# Creating a UL from nested array

Tags: javascript

I'm taking an intro JS course at my college and I have to build a `<ul>` with a nested array through JS.  I've already built an `<ol>` with a regular array for the first part of the assignment.  This is what I did:

```
window.onload = function(){

    fruits.sort();

    var ol = "<ol>"
    for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++){
        ol+= "<li>" + fruits[i] + "</li>"
    }ol += "</ol>"

    var myContainer = document.querySelector("#olContainer").innerHTML = ol;
};
```

For this array:

`var fruits = [ "Apples","Oranges","Pears","Grapes","Pineapples","Mangos" ];`

and the current nested array I'm working with, is this:

```
var directory = [
    {type: "file", name: "file1.txt"},
    {type: "file", name: "file2.txt"},
    {type: "directory", name: "HTML Files", files: [{type: "file", name: "file1.html"},{type: "file", name: "file2.html"}]},
    {type: "file", name: "file3.txt"},
    {type: "directory", name: "JavaScript Files", files: [{type: "file", name: "file1.js"},{type: "file", name: "file2.js"},{type: "file", name: "file3.js"}]}
];
```

I am thinking that using a switch statement would be better but I don't know how to iterate through each line of code and extracting the nested lists to indent them as a sublist.  I am required to build upon my previous JS function for the `<ol>` list

Comment: If you already have the code working for `<ol>`, you can put it into a function which accepts an argument so you can change the `ol` to `ul`. It is also preferable to use createElement and appendChild as manipulating innerHTML is hard on the browser memory and garbage collector.

Comment: yea but that one was for a single, flat array.  Its different for nested arrays.

Comment: what result you want for second example?

Comment: OK, I see, you can loop the directory array with various ways, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration so you could possibly use a for ... of loop, or use an Array.forEach loop. you decide. Inside the loop you can access the object containing type, name, and possibly the files array. e.g. `directory.forEach(item=>(console.log("name:", item.name)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with 2 `for` loops(nested for loops). Implement the same kind of for loop if the directory[i] has a `files` array.

```js
var directory = [
    {type: "file", name: "file1.txt"},
    {type: "file", name: "file2.txt"},
    {type: "directory", name: "HTML Files", files: [{type: "file", name: "file1.html"},{type: "file", name: "file2.html"}]},
    {type: "file", name: "file3.txt"},
    {type: "directory", name: "JavaScript Files", files: [{type: "file", name: "file1.js"},{type: "file", name: "file2.js"},{type: "file", name: "file3.js"}]}
];

window.onload = function(){
    var ol = "<ol>";
    for(var i = 0; i < directory.length; i++){
        ol += "<li>" + directory[i].name;
        if(directory[i].files) {
          ol += "<ol>";
          for(var j = 0; j < directory[i].files.length; j++) {
            ol += "<li>" + directory[i].files[j].name + "</li>";
          }
          ol += "</ol>";
        }
        ol += "</li>";
    }
    ol += "</ol>";

    var myContainer = document.querySelector("#olContainer").innerHTML = ol;
};
```

```html
<div id="olContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Do you get any error in the console or are your variable names different?

Comment: I've already solved it man.  Thanks anyways.  I've accepted your answer and upvoted you.  If you think that this was a well-asked question, could you also give me an upvote?

Answer (score 3):

Go recursive! It's basically a function that calls itself until certain condition, more details: https://www.sitepoint.com/recursion-functional-javascript/

> Recursion is a technique for iterating over an operation by having a
>   function call itself repeatedly until it arrives at a result. Most
>   loops can be rewritten in a recursive style, and in some functional
>   languages this approach to looping is the default.

you pass the `directory` to the function and loop through the first level values, if it's a `file` you add it to the list, otherwise you call the same function but you pass the second level list which is the value (the list of files), adding another nested `ul`, and so on ..

See the snippet below (based on your previous JS function for the `<ol>` list)

```js
var directory = [
    {type: "file", name: "file1.txt"},
    {type: "file", name: "file2.txt"},
    {type: "directory", name: "HTML Files", files: [{type: "file", name: "file1.html"},{type: "file", name: "file2.html"}]},
    {type: "file", name: "file3.txt"},
    {type: "directory", name: "JavaScript Files", files: [{type: "file", name: "file1.js"},{type: "file", name: "file2.js"},{type: "file", name: "file3.js"}]}
];

function createUl(list){
 
    var myUl = "<ul>";

    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
      if(list[i].type == "file")
        myUl+= "<li>" + list[i].name + "</li>";
      else{ // it's a directory
        myUl+= "<li>" + list[i].name + "</li>";
        myUl += createUl(list[i].files); // call the same function with the list of files
      }
    }

    myUl += "</ul>";
    
    return myUl;
}

var ulList = createUl(directory);
document.querySelector("#ulContainer").innerHTML = ulList;
```

```html
<div id="ulContainer">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use recursion. It's much cleaner to create elements directly and assign to their `textContent` than to type out HTML markup (you don't know for sure whether an input's text is safe to insert as HTML or not, after all):

```js
const input = [
    {type: "file", name: "file1.txt"},
    {type: "file", name: "file2.txt"},
    {type: "directory", name: "HTML Files", files: [{type: "file", name: "file1.html"},{type: "file", name: "file2.html"}]},
    {type: "file", name: "file3.txt"},
    {type: "directory", name: "JavaScript Files", files: [{type: "file", name: "file1.js"},{type: "file", name: "file2.js"},{type: "file", name: "file3.js"}]}
];

const outerUL = document.querySelector('ul');
appendObjToUL(input, outerUL);
function appendObjToUL(arr, ul) {
  arr.forEach(item => {
    ul.appendChild(document.createElement('li')).textContent = item.name;
    if (item.type === 'file') return;
    const dirLI = ul.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
    const dirUL = dirLI.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));
    appendObjToUL(item.files, dirUL);
  });
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```